# Adding a reference to a dll in a WCF project

Tags: .net, wcf, dll, reference

I've just started using WCF here at work and am trying to add a reference to a DLL that's available here at work.

I continually get this error:

> Error  1   Reference required to assembly 'Name.of.the.dll.here, Version=1.0.2824.29400, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=111111111' containing the implemented interface 'Name.of.the.dll.here.IInterface'. Add one to your project.

I've tried adding the reference a variety of ways (Productivity Power tools, VS2010 adding reference). The reference exists in my references folder.

The dll is targeting .NET 3.5 and my WCF is 4.0, but I'm not sure if that would make a difference.

Any clue why my refrence doesn't work?

Comment: Make sure that all the dependant assemblies of Name.of.the.dll are also added to the WCF project.

Comment: @Rajesh, add that as an answer and I'll accept it. Apparently I wasn't looking too hard and I had the `.Server` reference and it was telling me I needed the `.Shared` reference. Doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that all the dependant assemblies of Name.of.the.dll are also added to the WCF project